# Merge sorted inputs in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm a newbie to Haskell, and I'm trying to write an elegant function to merge an arbitrary number of sorted lists into a single sorted list... Can anyone provide an elegant and efficient reference implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if efficiency wasn't a concern I'd go with

```
merge = sort . concat
```

otherwise:

```
merge :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
merge [] = []
merge lists =
  minVal : merge nextLists
  where
    heads = map head lists
    (minVal, minIdx) = minimum $ zip heads [0..]
    (pre, ((_:nextOfMin):post)) = splitAt minIdx lists
    nextLists =
      if null nextOfMin
      then pre ++ post
      else pre ++ nextOfMin : post
```

note however that this implementation always linearly searches for the minimum (while for a large number of list one may wish to maintain a heap etc.)

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work:

```
merge2 pred xs [] = xs
merge2 pred [] ys = ys
merge2 pred (x:xs) (y:ys) =
  case pred x y of
      True  -> x: merge2 pred xs (y:ys)
      False -> y: merge2 pred (x:xs) ys

merge pred [] = []
merge pred (x:[]) = x
merge pred (x:xs) = merge2 pred x (merge pred xs)
```

Here, the function **merge2** merges 2 lists. The function **merge** merges a list of lists. The **pred** is predicate you use for sorting.

Example:

```
merge (<) [[1, 3, 9], [2, 3, 4], [7, 11, 15, 22]]
```

should return

```
[1,2,3,3,4,7,9,11,15,22]
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you use `case .. of {True -> ..; False -> ..}` when `if .. then .. else ..` would do the same?

Comment: Right, but applying pattern-matching on a boolean when if-then-else would be more idiomatic seems strange.  It can't be for the sake of strictness, so I'm wondering if Igor just has odd style (relative to what I use and commonly see) or some other motivation.

Comment: @ephemient: I wouldn't claim pattern matching is more idiomatic here. If-then-else would be equally good or better. In similar situations, I've seen pattern matching or guards more often than if-then-else, this is why I used it. But, again, I'm not that experienced with Haskell and might be looking at odd haskell code :) As a side note, this is matter of style and doesn't affect performance, since (for the compiler) if-then-else is syntax sugar around the pattern-matching case.

Comment: I was trying to say that if-then-else is more idiomatic (in my experience) than case-of-True-False.  But it really doesn't make a difference here... it just piqued my curiosity.

Comment: You should "merge pred = foldl (merge2 pred) []" instead... it would be clearer.

Comment: Epp: But what about infinite lists?

Comment: I'd use guards and `@`-patterns in order to avoid re-concatenations.

Answer (score 2):

Since I like taking advantage of infix operators and higher-order functions where it makes sense to, I would write

```
infixr 5 @@
(@@) :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
-- if one side is empty, the merges can only possibly go one way
[] @@ ys = ys
xs @@ [] = xs
-- otherwise, take the smaller of the two heads out, and continue with the rest
(x:xs) @@ (y:ys) = case x `compare` y of
    LT -> x : xs @@ (y:ys)
    EQ -> x : xs @@ ys
    GT -> y : (x:xs) @@ ys

-- a n-way merge can be implemented by a repeated 2-way merge
merge :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [a]
merge = foldr1 (@@)
```

Here, `xs @@ ys` merges two lists by their natural ordering (and drops duplicates), while `merge [xs, ys, zs..]` merges any number of lists.

This leads to the very natural definition of the [Hamming numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number):

```
hamming :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a]
hamming = 1 : map (2*) hamming @@ map (3*) hamming @@ map (5*) hamming
hamming = 1 : merge [map (n*) hamming | n <- [2, 3, 5]] -- alternative

-- this generates, in order, all numbers of the form 2^i * 3^j * 5^k
-- hamming = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,25,27,30,32,36,40,45,48,50,..]
```

---

Stealing [yairchu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40916)'s unimplemented [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941699/958654#958654):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List (foldl', unfoldr)
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

-- merge any number of ordered lists, dropping duplicate elements
merge :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [a]
-- create a map of {n: [tails of lists starting with n]}; then
-- repeatedly take the least n and re-insert the tails
merge = unfoldr ((=<<) step . M.minViewWithKey) . foldl' add M.empty where
    add m (x:xs) = M.insertWith' (++) x [xs] m; add m _ = m
    step ((x, xss), m) = Just (x, foldl' add m xss)

-- merge any number of ordered lists, preserving duplicate elements
mergeDup :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [a]
-- create a map of {(n, i): tail of list number i (which starts with n)}; then
-- repeatedly take the least n and re-insert the tail
-- the index i <- [0..] is used to prevent map from losing duplicates
mergeDup = unfoldr step . M.fromList . mapMaybe swap . zip [0..] where
    swap (n, (x:xs)) = Just ((x, n), xs); swap _ = Nothing
    step (M.minViewWithKey -> Just (((x, n), xs), m)) =
        Just (x, case xs of y:ys -> M.insert (y, n) ys m; _ -> m)
    step _ = Nothing
```

where `merge`, like my original, eliminates duplicates, while `mergeDup` preserves them (like [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110177)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941699/941828#941828)).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other posts, I would have `merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`

```
type SortedList a = [a]

merge :: (Ord a) => SortedList a -> SortedList a -> SortedList a
merge []     ys     = ys
merge xs     []     = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x < y     = x : merge xs (y : ys)
  | otherwise = y : merge (x : xs) ys

mergeAll :: (Ord a) => [SortedList a] -> SortedList a
mergeAll = foldr merge []
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note: if you want to have the optimal log n behavior when merging several lists (such as you'd get with a priority queue), you can do it very easily with a tweak to Igor's beautiful solution above. (I would have put this as a comment on his answer above, but I don't have enough reputation.) In particular, you do:

```
merge2 pred xs [] = xs
merge2 pred [] ys = ys
merge2 pred (x:xs) (y:ys) =
  case pred x y of
      True  -> x: merge2 pred xs (y:ys)
      False -> y: merge2 pred (x:xs) ys

everyother [] = []
everyother e0:[] = e0:[]
everyother (e0:e1:es) = e0:everyother es

merge pred [] = []
merge pred (x:[]) = x
merge pred xs = merge2 pred (merge pred . everyother $ xs) 
                (merge pred . everyother . tail $ xs)
```

Note that a real priority queue would be a bit faster/more space efficient, but that this solution is asymptotically just as good and, as I say, has the advantage that it's a very minor tweak to Igor's beautifully clear solution above.

Comments?

Comment: This is indeed asymptotically optimal, and actually uses fewer comparisons (though more other operations) than the priority queue approach, at least most of the time. My own Haskell versions of these algorithms were comparable in speed, but the divide-and-conquer approach performed more allocation and was far simpler to write. Note however that using an everyother function is not a good way to divide the list. You'd be better off just calculating the lengths and then using splitAt.